# Click event doesn't fire on first click but does everytime after

Tags: jquery

I am making my add to cart button update a span counter of items in the cart which works every time after you click the button once but does not work on the first click

I have tried using .on method which gives the same outcome and have tried using document.ready which also doesn't effect it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addToCart').on('click', function() {
    jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
      $("span.count").html(cart.item_count);
    });
  }); 
});
```

I expect the addToCart button to update the span.count on every click. The actual result is that it works after the first click.

Comment: cart.js returns a JSON of the cart it returns things like total price of the cart, item count of the cart etc I am using Shopify API

Comment: If anyone is trying to figure this out using the Shopify API I found that when using Ajaxify cart in the ajaxify-cart.liquid snippet you have to change the cartCountSelector:.. accordingly to where your cart count is stored as my span was in a class I had to change it from #CartCount to .count.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the solution provided below if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#addToCart', function() {  
        alert('button clicked');
        jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) { 
            $("span.count").html(cart.item_count);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#addToCart').on('click', function() { 
    alert("Hello"); 
  }); 
});
```

Please try it now Hope this ll helpful for you

Comment: With jquery version 3.2.1

Comment: All this does is remove the AJAX request...? How is this an answer. It's like curing the disease by killing the patient.

Comment: Yeah this does work but removes my AJAX request it does work on every click however doesn't return my cart count which I need.

Answer (score 0):

Button clicked every time, there is no issue with button click

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addToCart').on('click', function() {  
  alert('button clicked');

jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) { 
    $("span.count").html(cart.item_count);
});

}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shopify-cartjs/0.4.1/cart.min.js"></script>


<button id="addToCart" type="button">Add to cart</button>

<span>Cart Items: </span> <span class="count">0</span>
```

Comment: So that means the issue must be with the AJAX request? my issue is that when I click the button the first time the page is loaded it doesn't change the $(span.count) but when I press the button after the first click it then updates the ($span.count)

Comment: Yes, issue is with the ajax request, currently I am getting a message at my end "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stacksnippets.net/cart.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" . Check the documentation here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#get-cart , api taking time to return the response or check the readyState every time is the response ready, when its ready display the result then.

Comment: go through this link and try in this way: https://cartjs.org/pages/guide

Comment: Thanks for your help I have given it a look, does this mean that it probably isn't possible to have a ajaxed cart count unless I use this cartjs.org/pages/guide?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest you another way to update cart without using Ajaxify cart API. You should try once. I'm talking about [cart.js](https://cartjs.org/)

You just need to include below CDN in your theme header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shopify-cartjs/0.4.1/cart.min.js"></script>
```

After that you need to add tag "data-cart-render" in your html. It will automatically render cart item count inside the html tag. 
Example:

```
<span data-cart-render="item_count"></span>
```